# Xcode, UISwipeGestureRecognizer, ViewController transitions the wrong way?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I use the latest Xcode. So I put the SwipeGestureRecognizer inside my ViewController and connected it to another ViewController via a SHOW(push) seque. According to Attributes Inspector I can choose left/right. But when I build/run project and swipe left/right to transition between view controllers, the transition is up/down instead of right/left.

How do I make a right/left swipe make the VC move right/left instead of up/down?

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.0

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
present(dashboardWorkout, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

For objective c

```
CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self presentViewController:dashboardWorkout animated:false completion:nil];
```